# Firebase dynamic link not working as expected with custom domain

Tags: android, ios, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I have example.com custom domain and i want to let invite members to groups inside the app with dynamic links.

I want to use app.example.com/ as prefix.

All libraries installed, team id on firebase for ios is defined and imported with new google services plist.

So my url i prepared to my desire is this (building this as shortlink app.example.com/SOMERANDOMTHING)

```
https://app.example.com/?link=https://example.com/joingroup?groupid=SOMEGROUPID&apn=com.myorganization.myapp&amv=4&ibi=com.myorganization.myapp&isi=TEAMID&imv=4&ius=myapp
```

on iOS:

added to info.plist:

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
<array>
    <string>https://app.example.com</string>
</array>
```

Also added `applinks:app.example.com` to associated domains
And to URL Schemes, added com.myorganization.myapp

And my code on component did mount:

```
    componentDidMount() {

     var that = this

    dynamicLinks().onLink((link) => {

        
        that.handleDynamicLink(link)


    })


    if(Platform.OS == 'android') {


    dynamicLinks().getInitialLink().then((link2) => {

        if(link2) {

            

            that.handleDynamicLink(link2)

        }
```

*Problems*

**on Android**

1. When click link **re-opening app from start** and it calls
   getInitialLink, onLink not working (Thats why i selected platform
   for getinitiallink because on ios both functions working) .
2. Also when click link; no option like 'Open with MyApp' so link is
   not associated with MyApp, after clicking browser decides link to be
   opened with MyApp. (OK, it works but not cool)
3. If I add this to AndroidManifest:

   ```
   <data android:host="app.example.com" android:scheme="http"/>
   <data android:host="app.example.com" android:scheme="https"/>
   ```

   this time link opening with my app and android recognizes link
   belongs to MyApp but neither getInitialLink nor onLink works.

**on iOS**

onLink works, but its not transferring result to the app; its just transferring all link

```
https://app.example.com/?link=https://example.com/joingroup?groupid=SOMEGROUPID&apn=com.myorganization.myapp&amv=4&ibi=com.myorganization.myapp&isi=TEAMID&imv=4&ius=myapp
```

instead of

```
https://example.com/joingroup?groupid=SOMEGROUPID
```

So im stuck on these problems, thanks for your assist

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you use a link as a parameter of another link. I suggest replacing this with the following

```
https://app.example.com/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjoingroup%3Fgroupid%3DSOMEGROUPID&apn=com.myorganization.myapp&amv=4&ibi=com.myorganization.myapp&isi=TEAMID&imv=4&ius=myapp
```

If you use JavaScript to create a link manually, you can use `encodeURIComponent`

```
const link = encodeURIComponent('https://example.com/joingroup?groupid=SOMEGROUPID');
const url = `https://app.example.com/?link=${link}&apn=com.myorganization.myapp&amv=4&ibi=com.myorganization.myapp&isi=TEAMID&imv=4&ius=myapp`;
console.log(url)
```